# Attribuate a value to a select

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to put a variable data inside :eq to (see code below)

```
$.each(back, function(key, value)
{
    $.each(value, function(k, v) {
        if (k == 'pays_id') {
            var langue_fact = $("#form_facturation").find('#ld_langues');
            alert(v);
            v2 = parseInt(v);
            var v1 = ($("option:eq(" + v2 + ")", langue_fact).val());
            alert(v1);
            $("option:eq(" + v1 + ")", langue_fact).prop("selected", true);    
        }
    }
}
}
```

- `alert(v)` gives me, for example, 17
- `alert(v1)` give me "undefined"

It is impossible to me to attribuate a variable value

Comment: attribuate is not a word. I cannot understand your question.

Comment: back is back of php (ajax) it's a json object

Comment: You should provide your HTML code and example of `back` data.

Comment: By the way, not only there is extra `}`, but also `);` after `}` is missed for both `$.each`. The correct JS syntax is `$.each(function(k, v) { ... });`

Comment: Bear in mind that the `index` in `:eq(index)` is **zero-based**; is it possible your index is out of range? If you have 17 `option` elements, the last one is at `:eq(16)` .... and `:eq(17)` would give you `undefined`.

Comment: The real question is, why do you do `.find('#ld_langues')`, it's an ID, there shouldn't be any reason to use `find` to find it

Comment: @adeneo moreover, there is no need to put `var langue_fact = $('#ld_langues');` in internal `$.each`. It should be before external `$.each`.

Comment: Thank you to all of you and mainly to user3558931, the value exceded the available values... Thanks again

Comment: I think this would do the same thing, I see no reason what-so-ever for the inner loop? -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qu5nwawk/1/**